# Where can I configure "the default server setting"?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I've created a SQLServer Maintenance Task with SMSS. In the "Back Up Database Task", there's an option to compress the database.

One of the is to "Use the default server setting".

[image]

On some servers the default setting is to compress the backup, some are not. Where do I get the value of the default compression setting?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/view-or-configure-the-backup-compression-default-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pinal Dave has excellent tutorials on this [here](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/09/04/sql-server-configure-the-backup-compression-default-server-configuration-option/):

From SSMS you can set it by:

1. right-click a server in the Object Explorer and select Properties.
2. Click the Database settings node.
3. Click the Compress backup box.

[image]

You can also set it from TSQL with the following commands:

```
USE MASTER;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'backup compression default', 1;
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
GO
```